# ActionBar doesnt show title with spinner

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-arrayadapter

My `ActionBar` title or Activity Tile doesnt show with `Spinner` drop down added. Any Ideas on what wrong?? I've done alot of research but I'm not seeing problems

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener{

private static final int EDITOR_ACT_REQUEST = 504;
private static final int MENU_DELETE_ID = 1002;
private ActionBar actionBar;
private ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem> navSpinner;
private TitleNavigationAdapter adapter;
String curdate;
private int currentNoteId;
private ArgueDataS datasource;
List<ArgueItem> argueList;
public static ArrayAdapter<String> add;
private ArgueItem note;
TextView day;
String datastring;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    // Spinner title navigation data
    navSpinner = new ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem>();
    navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem("Argue Time", R.drawable.alarm));
    navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem("Top 10", R.drawable.topten));

    adapter = new TitleNavigationAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navSpinner);

    // assigning the spinner navigation     
    actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

to

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot show both the title and the spinner at the same time. The spinner should take the place of the title.